# How do I detect what scene the user was last on?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, back-button, detect, scene

I'm using cocos2d, and I want to know how I can detect what scene the user was last on before he/she pressed a button to go to my Settings scene from my pauseLayer scene. I need to know because there is 2+ ways to access the Settings scene, so I would need a special back button to go back to whatever scene the user was last at. Also, I could have 1 back button that has a method to go back to the last scene, not any specific one. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Based on your code sample, I suggest the following, which may not work exactly as written due to my lack of testing equipment :P.

First, add a method to your Settings class called +(id)nodeFromSource:(bool)bPauseMenu.

```
+(id)nodeFromSource:(bool)bPauseMenu
{
  if((self = [self node])
  {
    m_bPauseMenu = bPauseMenu;
  }
  return self;
}
```

Add bool m_bPauseMenu; in the class definition.

In the function you assign for your back button in Settings, implement the following code:

```
//for example...
-(void)backButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
  if(m_bPauseMenu)
  {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFlipAngular transitionWithDuration:1.2f scene:[pauseLayer node]]]; 
  }
  else
  {
    //trigger a replaceScene back to the other menu here 
    //(MyOtherLayer is the classname of your non-pause-menu layer that you came from...
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFlipAngular transitionWithDuration:1.2f scene:[MyOtherLayer node]]]; 
  }
}
```

Change the call in pauseLayer -(void)settings:(id)sender to:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFlipAngular transitionWithDuration:1.2f scene:[Settings nodeFromSource:true]]];
```

And wherever your other call to show the Settings layer is, make it say:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFlipAngular transitionWithDuration:1.2f scene:[Settings nodeFromSource:false]]];
```

The reason I called it nodeFromSource is so that one day you can replace the bool with some kind of reference and allow your layers to know things about the layers they came from.

I hope this works as-is. I've been over it a few times and can't see any obvious errors...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm a bit confused about your code. In the second part of your code, I get a warning saying "No '-initWithSource:' method found". I'm aware that I have to make this method/parameter, but how do I do that?
Also, what do you mean by setting cameFromPauseLayer true in pauseLayer, and false in Settings? 
In replaceScene, am I supposed to put that in Settings, so the back button goes back to pauseLayer? And also I'm getting the warning "'pauseLayer' may not respond to '+sceneWithSource:'. 
Sorry for the mass of questions, I'm just mainly not getting how to set the methods

Comment: Apologies, I don't have my Mac with me to do a tested example. Could you perhaps paste the pauseLayer class implementation here so I can show you what I mean in your app's context?

Comment: EDIT - I'm going to upload it and post it here in a few minutes